# How to Install 64bit msi /Setup.exe file from 32bit installer setup package

Tags: installshield, installscript, installshield-2012, basic-msi

I have created 32bit basic MSI project and I want launch/install 64bit msi package from 32bit installer setup file. I tried this using chained msi package but the problem I am facing is 64bit installer is not copying its files to 64 bit "Program Files" folder" instead it is always taking 32 bit Program files folder path to copy its files.

If I install 64bit msi package separately then it taking proper path but if try to install from 32 bit installer package as chained MSI then it not taking 64 bit program file folder.

I request anyone please give your valuable suggestion to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Windows Installer does not have support for creating a multi-architecture Windows Installer package that installs to 32-bit locations on 32-bit systems and 64-bit locations on 64-bit systems.
For creating a 64 bit setup file in installShield, you must do these steps:

-click on tools menu->options->Resource and in section "resource linker command line option" change the  "/MACHINE:iX86" to "/MACHINE:iX64".

-In installer designer click on the components and then for each component that is 64 bit click and change the 64-bit component attribute to "yes".

-change the "Template Summary" to a suitable value (e.g x64;1033).